# Is Qayim witr or nafl?

Tags: salat, islamic-basis, hanafi, witr

I recently started reading Qayim but not sure if they r counted as witr or nafl? What intention should one do before praying and should it be broken down in pair of 4 or 2-2-1 like witr

Comment: Witr is the last raka'a or the last odd number of raka'as of qiyyam. This is a very basic question and could easily be answered by research on the internet and even on this site.

Comment: As for the topic of intention you've already gotton an answer which makes clear that one shouldn't worry much about it, as what you have in mind to do is your intention.

Comment: @Medi1Saif it’s subjective as well depending on which school of thought u belong to.

Comment: So you prefer to follow blindly a school of thought which has no evidence for their complex way of making niyyah despite knowing that it was neither in accordance to the teaching of qur'an nor the practice of the prophet. Be aware that if the prophet would have practiced this we would have narrations quoting that he broke up a prayer and restarted it because of a false niyyah, which is not the case, but often happens to imams who follow certain madhhabs. As this way our prophet showed us how to correct mistakes in prayers... BTW knowing the truth and acting against it is a kind of kufr.

Comment: If you want an answer according a specific school of fiqh you should add this information to your post.

Comment: @Medi1Saif without going into much detail to your question. I have added tag of school of thought and If I knew or internet wasn’t confusing to answer my question I wouldn’t post it. I don’t troll in religion